# Updating GTS Version: 2.5.9 [ERROR|SystemProps.setProperty:521]

Tags: postgresql, opengts

How to solve property key for dmtp in opengts?
When I install open gts with postgresql I face that issue.

> Updating GTS Version: 2.5.9 [ERROR|SystemProps.setProperty:521]
>   Exception: Checking PropertyID existance: version.gts
>   org.opengts.dbtools.DBException: Record existance
>   SystemProps='version.gts' [org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR:
>   column "pro pertyID" does not exist]

Comment: I solved this problem. All column name should be in lowercase in postgresql. USe setproperty instead of setProperty.

Comment: You may give your solution as an answer and then accept it.